# Why are 'blueish' and 'bluish' both considered correct spellings?

Tags: adjectives, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

My nine year old son fought hard on this and is taking a stand on spelling *bluish* as *blueish*.  I'm certain his teacher will mark it as a spelling error in his writing... Several dictionaries have indicated both spellings are acceptable. A character in his story says

> What is that blueish white piece of
>   ice floating in the freezing cold
>   Antarctic waters?

Comment: Why are they both correct?  Not sure how this can actually be answered.

Comment: Cite a dictionary entry. Case closed?

Comment: I prefer blueish because both variants are so uncommon that it's best to keep the "blue" obvious. Perhaps some might think that bluish is a non-English, one-syllable word pronounced "blweesh" like the beginning of "Guido." **Roses are red. Violets are blueish. If it wasn't for Jesus, The pope might be Jewish.**

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562013/why-is-it-acceptable-to-use-both-across-and-acrossed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the NOAD and the OED define *blueish* simply as "spelling variant of *bluish*." (See also [*bluish*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/bluish) on the *Oxford Living Dictionaries*.)

Looking for both the words in the [*Corpus of Contemporary American English*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), there are 7 sentences containing *blueish* and 559 sentences containing *bluish*; for the *British National Corpus*, the numbers of the sentences are respectively 4 and 55.

Comment: I know Google results aren't most people's idea of a corpus, but they certainly show a far more equal distribution than the above figures.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's correct to say that both are correct spellings.  After looking through N-gram data, and
querying the venerable Fowler & Crystal's *A dictionary of modern English usage*, I find that *bluish* is clearly the preferred form.

Here's what Fowler & Crystal have to say:

> The only satisfactory rule, exceptions to which are very few, is this: If the suffix begins with a
>   consonant, the mute e is retained; if the suffix begins with a vowel, the mute e is dropped. 
>   Applying this [ ], we get (with the wrong results in italics, as a basis for exceptions): stalish;
>   loving; milage; livable; stirving; excitable; timous; movable; likely; dotard; judgement; hinging;
>   *singing*; *gaugable*; laughable, noticeable; mousy; changing; *hiing*; *gluy*; *duely*; bluish; *wholely*.

Another grammar book, *A Survey of English spelling* by a Edward Carney, explains the reasoning behind the rule:

> The {-e} has to be kept  when it is a marker of the pronunciation of the previous consonant as in
>   *gaugeable*, *manageable*, *noticeable*, *traceable*.  A spelling *{noticable} would invite   {c} =
>   /k/ before the  as in *practicable*. So, *singeing* with /ndʒ/ is kept different from *singing*
>   with /ŋ/.

Thus, the implication is that as there would be no ambiguity between the pronunciations of *blueish* and
*bluish*, the preferred spelling is the latter.

Here are the Google n-grams for usage; first for American English:

[image: Google Ngram1]

Next, British English:

[image: Google N-grambluish and blueish for British English]

It seemed that *blueish* did seem to enjoy some popularity as the preferred form for some years in both
America and Britain; peculiarly, between the years of 1786  - 1792 in Britain, and in 1788 - 1792 in America, Google Books shows that *blueish* enjoyed the advantage, being particularly applied to describe the color of
dyes and minerals.  (Here are [some citations from 1788 -
1791](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbs=bks%3A1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1788%2Ccd_max%3A1790&q=%22blueish%22&aq=f&aqi=m1&aql=&oq=).)  The nascent field of chemistry seems to  have preferred the odd spelling for some reason or the other.
But as you can see, despite that brief respite, since then *bluish* has reassumed its dominant position.

Comment: If you do an [Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=blueifh%2Cbluifh%2C+blueish%2C+bluish&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) including _blueifh_ and _bluifh_ you catch the use of the long _s_ pre-1820s that is often read as _f_ by Ngram. It tells a more dramatic story.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced there's a strong case for saying *blueish* is outdated or to be avoided for some other reason. It's just the less common of two variants, but personally I don't really have a preference.

I think an even more finally-balanced example is *clueing* / *cluing*, which occurs frequently in crossword-related writing. In that particular case I slightly favour including the **e**, though I certainly wouldn't take issue with it either way.

Comment: Other answers are showing evidence and references for their points. Can you find something showing _blueish_ is still in common use? (I think you referred to a Google result in a comment elsewhere.)

Comment: Point taken MrHen. I don't cite references as often as I could or should. But I wasn't really concerned with the actual occurence ratios - more with the question of whether it's actually *wrong* to use the less common one in cases like this. Plus as I'm sure you know, it's easy to find plenty of grammarians championing the short form. But lots of people persist in using the longer one even if they don't actively justify it.

Comment: As to the detail here, if I Google *bluish* I appear to get 7.8M hits, as against 1.2M for *blueish*. But I think Google is doing something odd here - perhaps because it wants to return results for *both* forms at once. Sometimes Google says there are only 5.3M hits for *bluish*, which I suspect is the real value for just that form.

Comment: You'd have to put quotes around the word in order for Google to give you results for just that spelling. Even then, if the webpage mentioned both forms, it would still show.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like *blueish* is an [outdated](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=blueish,bluish&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) spelling so I would advise him to spell it the same way as everyone else.  It's surely not worth the trouble is it?