# Why is it "noticeable" and not "noticable"?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

Here's something weird. I made a typo today in an essay and got minus points for writing "noticable" rather than "noticeable".

I thought you drop the vowel at the end of the verb when you add -able.

Why is it "noticeable" and not "noticable"?

Comment: It's discussed in the answer to the following question; you might be interested in reading it: [Why are 'blueish' and 'bluish' both considered correct spellings?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18824/why-are-blueish-and-bluish-both-considered-correct-spellings/18836#18836)

Comment: Technically it's not a "typo" if you did it on purpose. Common terms for it are "spello" or "grammo", or you could just say "I made a mistake". :^)

Answer (score 6):

Words do not always drop their final vowel when a suffix is added to them. Usually, I think, it is based on pronunciation.

'Pleasurable' can be easily pronounced.

'Noticable' looks like it ought to be pronounced 'notickable'.