# Is "ageing" the only exception?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, silent-letters, verb-forms

- have, having
- love, loving
- make, making
- take, taking
- give, giving
- hate, hating
- strive, striving

Etc. When a verb in its lemmatic form ends with "-e" then its present participle omits that letter.

Except that the British make an exception of the word **"age"** and write **"ageing".**

Are there other such exceptions? Are there any such exceptions in American usage?

Comment: In general, where there is a potential ambiguity between a (reasonably common) word ending with "..XXe" and one ending with "..XX", if the "e" is dropped (as per the usual "rule") when extending the word (as when adding "-ed" or "-ing"), either the "e" isn't dropped or the non-"e" word has the final consonant doubled or something similar.  Similar provisions are made when the "normal" modification would result in an awkward phonetic mapping.

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Dropped_.22e.22) says "British prefers **ageing**, American usually **aging**" and has more examples

Comment: “E” isn’t the only vowel to have such exceptions. “Skiing” is a rare double-i word.

Comment: "Skiing" is formed just as one would expect; the root form plus the suffix. There isn't any rule that would indicate removing a letter or doubling one, and indeed that doesn't happen.  So how is "skiing" relevant here?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are a small number of words aside from *ageing* that retain silent *e* before *-ing*; for some of them, this spelling is mandatory in American English as well as British English. For others, it is optional in both of these varieties of English. Retained silent *e* before *ing* seems to occur mainly after vowel letters (including *y*) or after the letter *g,* especially in the sequence *nge.*

Of course an *e* cannot be dropped when it is used as a single letter to represent a vowel sound directly before the suffix *-ing,* as in *being* or the trisyllables *segueing, sauteing* (or *sautéing*) and *appliqueing* (or *appliquéing*).

The digraph *ee* also retains both letters before *-ing* (*seeing, freeing, decreeing*), even though one *e* is lost as a rule when *-ee* comes before a suffix that starts with *e* such as *-ed, -er, -est.*

It is standard to drop the letter *e* that is used after the letter *l* or *r* to indicate a syllabic liquid or a sequence of schwa + liquid: *rambling, massacring,* and in British English *centring, manoeuvring.*

#### Mandatory

Two important mandatory examples: *dyeing* (not *dying*), *singeing* (not *singing*). Dropping the *e* in these words would cause ambiguity with the *-ing* forms of *die* and *sing* respectively.

Verbs ending in *-oe* also seem to mandatorily keep the *e* (*-oeing*):

- *-oe* pronounced as /oʊ/: *[toeing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/toe), [hoeing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hoe)*
- *-oe* pronounced as /uː/: *[canoeing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/canoeing), [shoeing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shoeing)*

This doesn't avoid any lexical ambiguity as far as I can tell, but perhaps helps indicate that they are not pronounced with the diphthong usually represented by *oi,* as in the onomatopoeia *boing*. *Going* and *doing* exist despite this, however.

- *-ie* pronounced as /i/ (unstressed): *[sortieing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sortie)*

This is complicated a bit by the existence of an alternative spelling *sorty,* which means that *sortying* is also a valid form. However, I haven't found any source that supports a paradigm like *sortie, sorties, sortying.* The same applies to *stymie,* as far as I can tell. At any rate, it's clear that the gerund/present participle form of a verb ending in *-ie* is generally *not* spelled with *-iing.*

- *-ae* pronounced as /eɪ/: *[spaeing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spae)*

This is a rare word meaning "prophesying", from [Scots](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/spae). There are probably other Scots verbs ending in *-ae* that have some use in English. All of the dictionaries I've consulted that list inflections for this word in modern English show it as retaining the *e* in its *-ing* form.

#### Optional

Retaining the "e" is optional for some verbs.

Ending in consonant sounds:

- *-nge* pronounced as /nd͡ʒ/: *[tingeing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tingeing), [twingeing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twingeing), [bingeing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bingeing), [whingeing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/whinge), [swingeing](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=swinge)**

  *I think the *e* of *swingeing* is usually kept to distinguish it from *swinging,* the *-ing* form of *swing,* but the AHD indicates that the *e* may be dropped anyway. The word *swinge* is used more in British English than in American English.
- *-gue* pronounced as /g/: *[rogueing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rogueing), [vogueing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vogueing)*
- *-ge* pronounced as /ʒ/: *lugeing*

Ending in vowel sounds:

- *-(e)ue* pronounced as stressed /(j)uː/: *[queueing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/queueing)†, [blueing](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=blueing)‡, [rueing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rue?a=british), [cueing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cueing), sprueing* (the last is uncommon, so it's in the OED but not in any free online dictionary that I know of)

  However, the verb *value,* where "ue" represents an unstressed vowel, always drops the "e" before *-ing*: *valuing*

  †There is also an ELU post on ["Queueing" or "Queuing"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60852/queueing-or-queuing)

  ‡Some people may consider "blueing" a misspelling; see the comments in [Why are 'blueish' and 'bluish' both considered correct spellings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18824/why-are-blueish-and-bluish-both-considered-correct-spellings)
- *eye* pronounced as /aɪ/: *[eyeing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/eye)*

#### Questionable

- *-ie* pronounced as /aɪ/: *vieing*? This looks very odd to me, and no major modern online dictionary lists it, but there are a small number of more-or-less contemporary examples from Google Books and from online sources (for examples, see [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/vie?family=vieing) and [wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/vieing)): these can probably just be regarded as misspellings, although they cannot be dismissed as typos because there are sources that use this spelling consistently (such as *[Social Ontology: Recasting Political Philosophy Through a Phenomenology of Whoness](https://books.google.com/books?id=8aPoBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA322&lpg=PA322&dq=%22vieing%22&source=bl&ots=aW2vXO9sGv&sig=X9MIWe4eRB5JM3bqqL_9ki2YAmI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxtb382YLUAhUowYMKHTl8Ab84ChDoAQgqMAE#v=onepage&q=vieing&f=false),* by Michael Eldred).
- the extremely rare *inoneing,* listed in the OED with two citations, from "in-" + "one" or the phrase "in one". Obviously *one* has a very non-standard pronunciation for a word ending in the letters "one".
- "routeing", mentioned by Muzer in a comment:

  > It's definitely archaic if ever used at all, but for some reason the rail industry in the UK uses "routeing" as the official spelling of eg "The Routeing Guide". I've very rarely seen this spelling outside this industry.

(Also see "[Skyping or Skypeing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30679/skyping-or-skypeing)".)

#### Nonstandard

There are also a number of more or less common nonstandard spellings/misspellings with this feature, such as "battleing" (for standard "battling"). The variability in people's intuitions about whether to include a silent "e" here seems similar to to the variability before the suffixes "-able", "-ish", and "-y".

---

Examples compiled with the help of [Onelook](http://www.onelook.com) wildcard search and [tchrist](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist)'s [post in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37556353#37556353).

I think there are better/more complete descriptions in many sources about English; you could probably find some on Google.

Comment: *Engageing* also has usage, perhaps on analogy with *ageing*.

Comment: @Clare: interesting. It [doesn't seem to be in any online dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=engageing&ls=a) though so I think it would be considered non-standard.

Comment: [Lots more where those came from](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37556353#37556353).

Comment: Re "toeing", note that "toing" is a different word, at least in British English - used in the phrase "toing and froing" meaning "going or moving to and fro". Also, it modern English it's "vying", not "vieing".

Comment: It's definitely archaic if ever used at all, but for some reason the rail industry in the UK uses "routeing" as the official spelling of eg "The Routeing Guide". I've very rarely seen this spelling outside this industry.

Comment: I think you are very unlikely to encounter anything other than "maneuvering" and "centering" in AmE, with the "E" being pronounced.

Comment: @Casey: Yes; in AmE, these verbs do not end in "e" in the lemma form, so the rule mentioned in the OP would not be applicable.

Comment: I remember seeing a difference (UK/US?) with *judgment* and *judgement* ... so can you have *judging* and *judgeing* also? My spell-checker says no to *judgeing*..

Comment: I think both "judgment" and "judgement" occur in the USA and the former is considered the more standard form. I don't recall ever having seen "judgeing".

Comment: The fact that so much had to be written to adequately explain the answer shows how "consistent" English spelling is.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood you; I thought you were also implying that one of the vowel in the last syllable disappeared in the progressive form, besides the spelling thing.

Comment: Dictionaries seem to have only *garaging*, but you do see *garageing* in print, as well as *portageing*.

Comment: I have seen *vying* and *stymying*.  Dunno why we can't have *eying*.

Comment: @AntonSherwood: You can. That's why I said it's optional to keep the "e" there.

Answer (score 1):

I have an old Collins dictionary in which 'ageing' is used to refer to mineralogy, and 'aging' for living beings.
I grew up in Australia and always assumed aging was the correct spelling for the word in common use.
Ageing seemed to 'creep in' in the late 20th century. I don't like it! Why should it differ from staging, paging, managing, foraging, ravaging etc etc.
Maxine Barry