# <ie ⟷ y> before the ·ing suffix

Tags: grammar, orthography, writing, phonology

Page 1579 of the CambridgeGEL reads

> For **die** the *ie* is the default spelling, so that the replacement
> works in the opposite direction: *ie* is replaced by *y* before the
> *·ing* suffix.

Why was a replacement *in either direction* diachronically necessary? (I infer its necessity from the wording *so that*)

Comment: Because English.

Comment: To avoid having three vowel letters in a row: _dieing_ looks bad, or something. There's no accounting for English spelling, however -- most of it is arbitrary.

Comment: @John: Stymied by [***stymieing**!*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stymieing%2Cstymying&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstymieing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstymying%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers [aunty](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=auntie%2C+aunty&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cauntie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caunty%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: - well, verbifying "to aunty" is maybe a bit of a stretch, so we can't really attach ***-ing*** to that one. But it's invariably [***untying*** rather than ***untieing***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=untieing%2Cuntying&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuntieing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuntying%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cuntieing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuntying%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers just wanted to point out the overall preferance for _-ie_ vs _-y_, where both are possible

Comment: I don't know if there are any better known or more clear-cut examples than ***stymieing***. The "ugly" spelling also dominates with ***birdieing*** and ***sortieing***, but they're both pretty unusual as *verb* forms, compared to ***stymie***. And  with more common verbs like ***to boogie*** we [again get the "opposite",](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boogieing%2Cboogying&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cboogieing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cboogying%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cboogieing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cboogying%3B%2Cc0) as per ***dying***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you’re Scottish, as a bonus you also get *ghillieing* and the ineffabling *tuilyieing* and *spulyieing* to boot. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers BTW, how can I get the NGram total relative freq? E.g. 3:1, 2:1, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _die_ is one syllable long (therefore it's stressed) and has a diphthong, while _boogie_ has the stress on the first syllable and the last syllable ends in a monophthong. The last vowel of both words is represented by what CambridgeGEL calles a _two letter symbol_

Comment: @HotLicks Well put.

Comment: Nobody has yet taken into account the usual syllabi(fi)cations.
According to Encarta,
_fre·er, 
fre·est, 
freed, 
free·ing, 
frees._

Comment: You can do limited "math" in NGrams. I'm not great at it, but I think it amounts to enclosing your search string in (brackets), then treating that as a numeric value (= number of hits) which can be added / subtracted / multiplied / divided by some *other* "value" represented by another bracketed search string - or just by a constant, as in **(search string) / 5**

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of "necessity" per se: the spelling conventions that happened to become standardized for English are largely arbitrary.

I think the following tendencies lie behind the spelling alternations for words like *die* and *try* (none of them are very strongly synchronically active):

- Word-final "i" is strongly dispreferred. Therefore, in most words where it would occur, "y" is used in its place (e.g. *cry, rely, copy* can be thought of as "standing for" **cri*, **reli*, **copi*).
- Non-grammatical words tend to have spellings that are more than two letters long, so words that end in an "i" sound and would otherwise be spelled with only two letters are spelled with a "silent e" at the end: e.g. *die, lie, tie, vie, pie.* A few words end in *-ye* instead of *-ie*: *rye, dye, lye.*
- Silent *e* is usually present or added between an *i* (word-finally, *-y*) and the suffix *-(e)s.*

  This seems similar also to the use of *-es* in the verb forms *does, goes,* and various noun plurals in *-oes.*
- Silent *e* is usually absent or "dropped" before the suffix *-ing*.

  This is more of a default, rather than a strong dispreference for words ending in *eing,* and there are multiple exceptions that I have already tried to cover in an answer to a previous question: [Is "ageing" the only exception?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/390330/is-ageing-the-only-exception) Other suffixes that show similarly variable behavior are *(e)y,* *(e)able,* *(e)ish.*
- the sequence "ii" is strongly dispreferred and so "y-ing" is used in place of "i-ing"

Both the dispreference for word-final *i* and the dispreference for *ii* might be related to the concept of "[minim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minim_(palaeography)) letters" and the idea that in certain types of handwritting these letters are less visually distinctive, especially when they occur in sequence, than other letters.

As I said, these are obviously not hard constraints on contemporary spelling so there are plenty of words that don't follow these tendencies; e.g. *ski, skiing,* Latinate plurals like *radii,* abbreviations like *bi.*

Comment: It seems that by and large, the spelling of verbs ending in /ai/ seemed to settle down from about 1600. From the OED, the chronology of the spelling of **Dying**,: 1435, deyng; 1450, dieng; 1556,  dying; 1563,  deand; 1590 and onwards, dying. **Spying**, 1338, spiyng; 1398, spying; c1430, spiyng; 1495, spienge; 1523, spyeng; a1568 and thereafter, spying. **Lying** 1382, liggynge; 1455, liggyng; c1470, liggand; 1488 lyand; 1495, lying; 1564, lieng; 1583, lieng;1619 and thereafter lying.